# How to create a date field in a Form in word that can be empty

Tags: vba, ms-word

Using Word 2010

We're creating a form in Word for leave applications. We have chosen all the relevant text fields to be filled out, and of course date fields.

We want the form to be able to be completed either digitally (using the date field) or printed and filled out. That is where the issue comes in because it fills the field in with a place-holder date.

I have contemplated creating a script that when printing, checks if the field has the placeholder date, if so, delete's it before printing.

Is there another way to have the date empty until filled in. Is there a format for a normal text box which could force a format similar to DD/MM/YYYY?

Comment: You can consider using `Application.DocumentBeforePrint Event` as described [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff845163%28v=office.14%29.aspx).